# View windows vault with mimikatz

Tags: windows

I'm following [this article](http://blog.digital-forensics.it/2016/01/windows-revaulting.html) to decrypt windows vault (On Windows 7 x86)

I've added two credentials for testing,

[image]

But in either Local or Roaming, I have nothing in the Credentails folder

[image]

Where I only have a policy file

[image]

What could be wrong here?

And if I'm going to do this with mimikatz alone, what commands should I use? The [official wiki](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/module-~-vault) is empty

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this to show important files in your explorer?

[image: Maybe try this?]

Answer (score 1):

Despite 'Vault' name in the Windows control panel, credentials still stored as legacy: `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Credentials`

Take a look in [mimikatz_dpapi.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlQCT5PF61KjmCAhhYO0flOcZE4e) for DPAPI-related storage locations.

And you can deal with them with: `dpapi::cred /in:file` using [mimikatz](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz), see [this Wiki entry](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/howto-%7E-decrypt-EFS-files) (this is the origin of the above link).